# URLDownloadToFile API, how can it be used asynchronously?

Tags: c++, file, url, download

How can this API `URLDownloadToFile` be used asynchronously? I need to show the progress of the download via SendMessage to a client window, which can't be done as the API appears to be synchronous and it never sends the OnProgress until the download completes.
I have also seen some example codes involving `IMoniker` interface, but I can't find an example that involves asynchronous reading of data and saving them to a file.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [URLOpenPullStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775128(VS.85).aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Run it in a new thread using CreateThread().  Then your main thread can process the message queue as normal.